# Flutter : want to excecute code in try-catch but async

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, try-catch

hi everyone I want to execute some codes inside try-catch.
if all conditions in try are met, then I want to change the screen.
but because the conditions has await, the screen changes before the conditions are checked.

So is there a way to solve this?
Is there anyway to wait for others to end and then do Navigator.push?

I tried Future.dowhile() but not working..

```
try {
        await savePhoneNum(_phoneNumberController.text);

        await postAppToken(
            tokenValue,
            _packageInfo.appName,
            _packageInfo.version,
            Theme.of(context).platform.toString().substring(15),
        _phoneNumberController.text);

        final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationId,
        smsCode: _smsController.text,
        );

        Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomBarScreen()));
        
    } catch (e) {
      
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${e.toString()}')),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, just check if `PhoneAuthProvider.credential` is a future function or not. If it is then add `await` in front of it. Like this `await  PhoneAuthProvider.credential`.

Comment: @AloysiusSamuel i tried, and it gives me this message : 'await' applied to 'PhoneAuthCredential', which is not a 'Future'

Comment: You can go inside `savePhoneNum` and `postAppToken` functions and check if you can add `await` keyword in some of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationId,
        smsCode: _smsController.text,
        );
```

use then statement after the function calling

```
final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationId,
        smsCode: _smsController.text,
        )..then();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use chain functions on async calls. for example `await myFun1().then((result) => async callbackFunction).then((nextResult) => nextCallback)` and so on.  this way you make sure all your logic executes in correct way.